# What non-canon elements were added to The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, canon, the-hobbit

Taking into account the *Lord of the Rings* Appendices and all of Tolkien's other writings (including his letters) I'd like to know what elements of the film were *entirely* created by Peter Jackson and Company.

If this question is too broad as asked, please let me know how I might improve it!

(I hope this question isn't going to be confused with [What elements from non-Hobbit Tolkien canon have been included in the Hobbit movie?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27848/what-elements-from-non-hobbit-tolkien-canon-have-been-included-in-the-hobbit-mov))

Comment: That stupid ax in the head...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27848/what-elements-from-non-hobbit-tolkien-canon-have-been-included-in-the-hobbit-mov

Comment: @MajorStackings The answers for that linked question and this one are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @MajorStackings - the other one asks for **canon** elements :)

Comment: @Keen - now you can have a real life example for your meta Question :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure Greedo shot first in canon.

Comment: I can only assume @MajorStackings is joking, as I linked to that very question in my question, noting its difference! (And nobody would post a link to a possible duplicate without actually *reading* the question first... Would they?)

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt Nope. I wasn't joking. I *was* confused and didn't pay close enough attention. Sorry! +1 :)

Comment: Rhosgobel rabbits.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that all that necromancer stuff, and a lot of the pale orc stuff wasn't in the actual book.  as far as saying that stuff is absolutely non-cannon though, that's very hard to say, even having read the major books(simirillian, hobbit, lotr trillogy).

Comment: @SamIam, the necromancer is definitely mentioned in other Tolkien works, so he's not a Peter Jackson invention. I'm not 100% certain about the pale orc.

Comment: after a quick re-reading of the first chapter, I found one minor thing:  Thorin wasn't late to the initial meeting at Bilbo's house, in-fact he came in with gandalf and the last bunch of dwarves.

Comment: Gandalf killed the goblin king before riddles in the dark(in-fact bilbo was there to see it)

Comment: If they would have titled the movie 'A Medieval Tale' I would have liked it a bit and even had a passing thought that it seemed to have some elements of J.R.R Tolkien's 'Hobbit' mixed in. As it was, my expectations were dashed before the party was over.

Comment: @DVK Greedo used a blaster, not a canon ;-)

Comment: Worst of all, not including enough of Beorn... ok you said adding... Adding too much anti-Beorn?

Answer (score 43):

I'll take a stab at this since I was so disappointed that they didn't try to follow the proper story more.

- Thorin wasn't late, he arrived with the group of dwarves who fell in the door when Bilbo opened it and that was the same time that Gandalf arrived.
- The dwarves brought a lot more instruments to play (I always thought that was a little silly and wondered where they all went the next day when the dwarves set off. I can't imagine they brought drums and violins on the journey).
- The morning after the party Gandalf comes around to hurry Bilbo out the door and that is the first time he gets anything in writing about the contract. It was actually left on his mantle but he didn't notice it.
- Gandalf doesn't leave the dwarves on the road out of anger. No one actually noticed he was gone until they needed him.
- The trolls don't steal the ponies. The company is having a miserable night because of the rain and can't light a fire but when they spot a fire off in the distance they send Bilbo to investigate.
- Bilbo tries to steal a purse from one of the trolls in order to prove his burglar skills but it yells and gets him caught.
- The other dwarves get caught without any real fight when they come looking for Bilbo except Thorin who does put up a fight but is overwhelmed.
- It is Gandalf, not Bilbo, who confuses the trolls by throwing his voice until the dawn.
- There is none of this pale orc nonsense in the book and the wolves don't come until they reach the other side of the Misty Mountains.
- Radagast and the stupid rabbit sled thing -- 'nuff said.
- There should not be any of this animosity between Elrond's people and the dwarves. In fact, the elves of Rivendell are expecting the company and singing songs about them when they arrive.
- There was no council with Saruman and Galadriel. All the stuff about Dol Guldur is happening but is outside the scope of the book. (I kinda don't mind them adding stuff like this since it did, at least, happen in the original story)
- The dwarves did not leave Rivendell without Gandalf.
- They did not walk around on the giants knees -- that part of the movie was just stupid IMHO, all we needed next was Optimus Prime to show up and save the day.
- Gandalf was in the cave with the dwarves when the goblins captured them. He killed several and then just managed to sneak inside before they closed the door.
- Bilbo was taken before the Great Goblin with the rest of the dwarves. He was rescued by Gandalf, same as everyone else and Gandalf killed the Great Goblin and then he and the company fled.
- They were in tunnels, not big open spaces with lots of rope and wood bridges.
- Bilbo was lost in the flight after the Great Goblin was killed. That was when he found the ring while fumbling around in the dark.
- The riddle match happened while the dwarves and Gandalf escaped. Bilbo was noticeably later getting out.
- There was no mention of Bilbo having blurred sepia vision while wearing the ring. (I know, this was more creative liberty carried over from LOTR)
- Bilbo lost his buttons getting out of goblin's gate to the outside, not getting away from Gollum. This was kinda important because A) it was still daylight which is why the goblins hadn't given chase yet and B) the goblins spotted Bilbo's shadow.
- It was the wolves (not wargs) and goblins (not that stupid pale orc) that treed the dwarves and Gandalf. They did not push the trees over the edge of a cliff.
- There was no climatic rescue of Thorin by Bilbo.
- They could not see Erebor from the slopes of the Misty Mountains.

This is all I can think of off the top of my head after only seeing the movie once. There are probably a lot more since it seems they didn't even try to stick to the original story. I can't wait to see how badly they mangle everything in the next two movies.

Comment: "There is none of this pale orc nonsense in the book" and no mention of it in any of Tolkien's other writings?

Comment: Perhaps I'm nitpicking, but a lot (most?) of this is stuff that was *changed*, rather than stuff that was *added*. (And things that are mentioned in other Tolkien writings, like Dol Guldur and the council with Saruman & the elves, was specifically excluded by the question. We're looking for things that PJ & company *made up*.)

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt - Azog does indeed exist, and he did kill Thorin's grandfather, but that happens outside the scope of the novel (and Azog actually died over a hundred years before the events in the Hobbit)

Comment: Ah, well if anything in the canon is allowed then I guess we are lucky that he didn't change the story to Bilbo finding a Silmaril and then having a game of riddles with Morgoth.

Comment: Or maybe he is saving that for [The Silmarillion movie](http://www.thesilmarillionmovie.com/) -- he should be able to stretch that into at least 5 or 6 parts.

Comment: @SSumner, So all they did was make it so that the reports of the death of Azog were incorrect? Quite a clever change, really.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt - kind of. Change in placement in the timeline too, and he wasn't "reported" dead - Dain Ironfoot whacked his head off

Comment: @SSumner, As I understand it, Thorin was alive during the Battle of Azanulbizar, so how does it change things in regards to timeline placement? (Sorry, I'm not super up on my lore :)

Comment: Maybe it didn't - it made it seem closer to the events of the Hobbit, but Thorin was old enough to participate (he was 53), though I don't remember if it was said in the books that he did.

Comment: @SSumner So there may not have been a timeline change, then?

Comment: It's possible that other than Azog not dying that there was no timeline change, yes

Comment: @Martha In that case, I think the answer is that nothing was added to the film that didn't have a basis in the wider Tolkien cannon. Even the Rhosgobel rabbits make sense. The story of The Hobbit was embellished, but largely consistent with the source material.

Comment: It may be "consistent" with the cannon as a whole, but it is not true to the spirit of the original story.

Comment: To me, the whole film felt rushed in places and padded in others as if they had to really stretch to make it into a trilogy.

Comment: @RonSmith The film felt entirely consistent with the spirit of the original story to me? :-/

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt I guess we will have to agree to disagree. I was very disappointed considering how well he did with the LOTR movies.

Comment: @RonSmith Yeah, I agree that they're different, but have you read The Hobbit lately? It ain't great :)

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt I re read The Hobbit right before the movie came out and I read it to and with my daughter several time in the past few years. I thing it is an excellent story. It was never meant to be the serious epic that was LOTR. That is precisely why I say they failed to keep with the spirit of the story. They tried to turn The Hobbit into a LOTR story and it is not that. It should have been kinder and gentler.

Comment: I appreciate the desire to get into all the big bad stuff that is going on behind the scenes but never enters into the story.  That should have been left for its own separate movie(s) and would have made a nice buffer in between TH and LOTR.

Comment: @RonSmith Fair enough. I felt the film WAS pretty gentle in spirit, but each to his own.

Comment: One correction: it *was* Wargs that treed the company.  From chapter 6: "But even the wild Wargs (for so the evil wolves over the Edge of the Wild were named) cannot climb trees." and "Every now and then all the Wargs in the circle would answer their grey chief all together".

Comment: Does this answer describe the movie (as compared to the book), or the book (as compared to the movie)? It seems to veer between the two — which is confusing to those who don't know both well.

Comment: I attempted to describe the differences between the book and the movie, not one or there other.

Answer (score 18):

The addition that most strongly contradicts Tolkien's timeline was to have Radagast discover the Necromancer at Dol Guldur. It will allow the movies to have one coherent story but grates really badly against canon.

You see, in the canon timeline the Necromancer had first appeared at Dol Guldur almost 2000 years before the events of The Hobbit, and Gandalf had gone there (and confirmed that it was Sauron) almost 100 years before, which was also the time when he acquired the map and key from Thorin's dying father.

This is vitally important because it explains why Gandalf personally accompanied and helped Thorin on his quest: it was really a carefully planned diversion to prevent Smaug from helping Sauron when the White Council attacked Dol Guldur.

Comment: Interesting! Of course, that's all ret-conned. Tolkien never planned that when he wrote The Hobbit, so it's fair to say that an adaptation of the book might give him another reason for joining Thorin.

Comment: +1 IMO this is the most major deviation from canon; the other stuff was just fluff compared to this.

Answer (score 5):

Excellent answer which sums up most of my disappointments with the film.

I'll just add that the coming of Smaug is different in the film. All those homeless dwarves roaming the plain would have been a nice feast. In fact the dwarves inside were all killed except for Thror and Thrain who mysteriously appeared on the mountain-side somewhat singed (setting up the later revelation of the secret passage). The Wood-Elves weren't there and didn't refuse to help. Also Thorin seemed to already have the map but not the key, and Balin would never question Thorin's actions in the presence of others.

Gandalf didn't use a moth to seek help (similar invention in LotR) but the Lord of the Eagles just happened to notice the commotion. Bilbo didn't make any heroic gestures of saving Thorin, or anyone else, during the goblin attack while they were in the trees.

Comment: Yes great part of dwarves in the Mountain were killed, but (as it later turned out) there were more survivors that escaped and of course those who were outside their halls in the time of the attack. Those who were left alive in majority fled east to Iron Hills to live with Dain's people. Also elves would never be able to help them in time due to large distance (it took 5 days for them to march to Long Lake after Smaug's death, not to mention anywhere close to the Lonely Mountain).

Answer (score 0):

Another non canon element where that Thorin actually were outside the castle when it was under attack. That was the only reason he survived. His dad and granddad took the secret exit. It wasn't as manny people that survived in the book. Most of them got killed.

Comment: Castle = the lonely mountain?