# What kind of rabbits did Radagast use to pull his sleigh?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, movie, the-hobbit

In the Hobbit movie, Radagast has a sleigh that is pulled by rabbits. At one point he says something along these lines to Gandalf:

> These are ??? rabbits! I'd like to see them try (to catch me)

What kind of rabbits are they, and where in Middle-Earth/the Tolkien universe do they fit in?

Comment: Rabbits?! Pulling a sleigh?!  That's stupider than an ax in the head...

Comment: At least it sounds like they weren't treated as siblings of the Killer Rabbit of Caerbannog:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbit_of_Caerbannog

Comment: OTOH, Killer Rabbits vs. Orcs would've been cool...

Comment: I'd watch that movie

Comment: Actually, if the Valar had had Killer Rabbits, I think the war with Melkor would've been over very quickly in the first age.

Comment: [Jackalopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackalope)?

Comment: This question needs to be protected

Comment: What kind of rabbits did Radagast use to pull his sleigh? ... BIG ones.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

They are **Rhosgobel rabbits**, but they are [an entirely original concept that appears in the movie alone](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/28249/2217).

Rhosgobel, anyway, is where Radagast lives.

> Radagast lived for much of his time in Middle-earth at Rhosgobel in the Vales of Anduin, on the western eaves of Mirkwood, between Carrock and the Old Forest Road, near the Gladden Fields, its name deriving from Sindarin *rhosc gobel* meaning "brown village".<sup>1</sup>

Mirkwood is this forest. The Misty Mountains are on the left (the Shire being farther in the West) and the Lonely Mountain on the right. Going South, you'd see Rohan, Gondor and Mordor.

[image: Portion of a map of Middle-earth, focused on Mirkwood and its environs, from Lórien in the south to the Grey Mountains and from Rivendell in the west to Erebor.] [Source](https://blog.lefigaro.fr/hightech/middle-earth-map.jpg)

---

<sup>1: Tolkien, J. R. R. (1980), Christopher Tolkien, Unfinished Tales. See this [Wikipedia note](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radagast#cite_note-ut-1).</sup>

Comment: Rhosgobel is mentioned in The Fellowship of the Ring also. At the council of Elrond, Gandalf says: "Not far from Bree I came upon a traveller sitting on a bank beside the road with his grazing horse beside him. It was Radagast the Brown, who at one time dwelt at Rhosgobel, near the borders of Mirkwood." Later it is said that some of the scouts sent out by Elrond "had climbed the pass at the source of the Gladden River, and had come down into Wilderland and over the Gladden fields and so at length had reached the old home of Radagast at Rhosgobel".

Answer (score 12):

The line is "These are Rhosgobel Rabbits, I'd like to see them try!"  [Rhosgobel](https://www.glyphweb.com/arda/r/rhosgobel.html) is the old home of Radagast the Brown.  The house is said to have been located between the Carrock and the Old Forest Road, on the western borders of Mirkwood as per the *Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring* as well as *Unfinished Tales*.  The rabbits themselves where added for the movie version and do not show up in Tolkien's works.

Comment: I heard "Ruskavel" instead of "Rhosgobel." I am not as much as a LOTR geek as most but my hearing is ok :P